# Bridge for Onion site

Tags: onion-services, bridge

It's possible to use a bridge on Tor to hide the fact that you are using Tor.  Is it also possible to have a bridge on your .onion site to hide the fact that you are hosting one?  If so, how can this be done using Tor on Linux?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One by one:

- **No, you can't** hide the fact that you're **using** Tor, because when you're using an *Exit node* to reach a clearnet/internet site the address of the exit node is exposed and these addresses are few nowdays, sadly - so they are enumerated and often marked as an exit node by the reverse DNS lookup
- **Yes, you can** hide the fact that you're **trying to connect** to Tor by using pluggable transport with bridges - that's what the pluggable transports are made for! Try using OBFS transports, especially the last one. Using just pure bridges is still detectable by DPI, but can help you as well in some cases
- **Yes, you can** use bridges for **any role/purpose** of the tor node, i.e. not just for a client, but also for the node that is hosting a hidden service - there's no limits at all for that!

Comment: For the first one, I meant hiding Tor from ISPs, sysadmins, etc.  Do you know how to do this for Ubuntu?  Or would it be better to ask a question on askubuntu?

Comment: you mean to hide the binaries from them? like having a QubesOS portable bootable flash?